# dylib for iPhone 3.1.2 is too short, wrong cputype/cpusubtype

Tags: iphone, dynamic, loading, dylib, iphone-sdk-3.1.2

I've been trying to compile a dylib to use in a little prototyping experiment however dlopen() says that my dylib is Mach-O but that the file is too short. Should it be padded with something?

I have the latest everything so that shouldn't be a problem.

lipo spits this out when I try to merge the i386 and armv6 arch's together:

lipo: specifed architecture type (armv6) for file (libTest.A.armv6.dylib) does not match it's cputype (7) and cpusubtype (3) (should be cputype (12) and cpusubtype (6))

`Any thoughts?`

Answer (score 0):

See /usr/include/mach/machine.h, which (in particular) contains

```
#define CPU_TYPE_X86        ((cpu_type_t) 7)
#define CPU_SUBTYPE_I386_ALL            CPU_SUBTYPE_INTEL(3, 0)
```

This suggests that libTest.A.armv6.dylib is actually an i386 library.

Comment: i'm on the latest macbook pro, and arch returns i386 but i get the same error as in the question, what flags should i use with ./configure to get it to work? should i use --arch=x86_64 ?

Comment: maybe i should say that it's for building ffmpeg